# How to display the number of items inside for loop using hoganjs template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hogan.js

I have a object, I want to limit the number of Items displayed at the front end. The problem is that I'm using hogan js template for rendering my HTML. I didn't understand how to implement the logic in hogan js.

***Routes*** Code Where I set the Object :

```
res.render('search', {
          layout : 'layouts/main/default',
          partials:{
                   Header: "includes/main/header",
                   Slider: "includes/main/slider",
                   Contact: "includes/main/contact",
                   Footer: "includes/main/footer",
                   Search : "includes/main/search"
          },
          title   :  'Result',
          product :  data.product, //here I set the product Json data 
          total   :  totalProducts,
 })
```

Product ***JSON***  contains the data like this:

```
{ product: 
   [ { link: 'http://www.walmart.com/ip/Straight-Talk-Samsung-Prepaid-Galaxy-GRAND-Prime-LTE-S920C-Smartphone/46716301',
       image: 'http://i5.walmartimages.com/dfw/dce07b8c-39c4/k2-_b4b0e2b5-8534-4979-8953-aae10886c54c.v1.jpg',
       name: 'Straight Talk <mark>Samsung</mark> Galaxy GRAND Prime 4G LTE Android Prepaid Smartphone',
       price: '149',
       logo: '/images/wal.png',
       siteName: 'Walmart'
      },
      { link: 'http://www.walmart.com/ip/T-Mobile-Samsung-Galaxy-S4-Prepaid-Smartphone/43388843',
       image: 'http://i5.walmartimages.com/dfw/dce07b8c-d26b/k2-_8f1131b8-61d3-4760-8129-9a740eb10e9b.v1.jpg',
       name: 'T-Mobile <mark>Samsung</mark> Galaxy S4 Prepaid Smartphone',
       price: '149',
       logo: '/images/wal.png',
       siteName: 'Walmart' 
      },
      ......
      ......
     ]
}
```

***Search.hjs*** contains the html code:

```
<div class="row">
     {{#product}}
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="center">
           <img src="{{image}}"  class="img-rounded" height="100" width="100"/>
           <h4>{{name}}</h4>
           <h4>{{price}}</h4>
           <a href="{{link}}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">View Details</button></a>
        </div>
     </div>
     {{/product}}
</div>
```

I want to display only three products at a time.

Answer (score 1):

> I didn't understand how to implement the logic in hogan js.

Hogan (and Mustache, on which it's based) is called a *logic-**less*** templating engine. It doesn't provide you with logic to perform these sorts of tasks from within the template.

> I want to limit the number of Items displayed at the front end

You have to limit the array-size server-side:

```
product : data.product.slice(0, 3)
```

Comment: If by "front end" you mean the template, then no, not really. If you mean "the browser", then you can obviously limit the length of the list that's being shown using CSS or JS, but it would still mean that the entire list is rendered _and_ transferred. Also not great.